# How can I keep the GraphQL Playground updated with my app's authorization headers?

Tags: express, graphql, graphql-playground

I have integrated a GraphQL server into my Express application. To ensure security, my requests are protected, and I have to update the authorization header in the GraphQL Playground every few hours. However, constantly updating the authorization headers manually is becoming cumbersome.

Is there a way to automate the process of keeping the GraphQL Playground updated with my app's authorization headers? I want the authorization headers used in my Express app to be automatically applied in the GraphQL Playground, eliminating the need for manual updates every few hours.